# Avoid dependent equations when applying Kirchoff's Laws

Tags: electric-circuits

I tutor college students in Physics. In particular, we are currently working on solving circuits using Kirchoff's Laws. In a recent problem, I ended up with a system of linearly dependent equations and was unable to solve for the unknown currents until I replaced one of the equations with another equation that was linearly independent.

What is a good rule of thumb to avoid this kind of situation? In this particular situation, we had 4 unknown currents and we set up 4 equations just using Kirchoff's Loop Law. It seems that in such a situation with n unknowns, n equations just from the loop law) will always be linearly dependent. Is this the case? So is it a good idea to use at most n-1 equations from the loop law and resort to the node law to get the rest of our equations?

Comment: Not sure I understand why you could not just solve n equations with n unknowns. What does "linearly dependent" mean - was the determinant zero? Perhaps you could expand your question with the example.

Comment: Did you look up the algorithms for nodal and modified nodal analysis?

Comment: @Floris Linearly dependent means the same thing that it does in a more conventional vector space. One of the equations can be written as a linear combination of the others (and yes, that implies that written in matrix form the determinate is zero). There are easy ways to avoid certain linear dependencies, but as far as I know avoiding them all requires some understanding of the particular system you are looking at.

Comment: @dmckee thanks. It seems to me that whenever this happens you are simply missing at least one more equation / constraint - and I agree that rather than a general rule you need to examine the individual system. I find that "zero net current into each node" often results in better behaved equations than "zero voltage around each loop", but I struggle to explain why.

Comment: For KCL, as long as you make equations for all except one node, you should not have any redundant equations.

Comment: @Floris Yes, if I had turned my equations into a matrix, the determinant of the matrix would be zero. (This is one of many equivalences of "linear dependence".)

Comment: @CuriousOne This student is in a basic physics class. They are not covering mesh current or node voltage analysis.

Comment: @Floris I have found that using "zero net current into each node" you can still easily develop a system of linearly dependent equations.

Comment: @Code-Guru: For simple circuits you just wing it and tell students that there has been decades of algorithm research for the optimal extraction of equations from complex networks that has yielded reliable solutions. As long as you don't require them to do things in a test that you don't teach, it's OK to keep it simple. Those who care can always read up on the topic.

Comment: @CuriousOne "there has been decades of algorithm research for the optimal extraction of equations from complex networks that has yielded reliable solutions." Are you saying this is still an open problem (at least for a general solution)?

Comment: Now I'm getting side-tracked by my own intellectual curiosity. My OP is regarding "simple" textbook questions for circuit analysis in a 100-level college physics class.

Comment: @Code-Guru: For simple circuits? No, not at all. But today's industrial circuit simulation has to deal with hierarchical multi-level and multi-domain circuits that can contain millions of elements. Efficiency is a huge problem for those kinds of simulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For planar circuits I have found the following pattern to work in most cases.
1) Note voltage values or assign voltage variable names **with polarities** to every circuit element.

2) Remembering that elements which are in series have identical currents through them, assign current values or current variables with directions.  It's convenient to have the current direction pointing from + to - signs through the circuit element.

3) Write Kirchoff voltage loop equations for every ``simple'' loop, i.e., loops which do not enclose other loops (they can touch others, but can't surround them). Pay attention to what the entering polarity of the voltage is. If you enter the + end, add the voltage assigned. If you enter the - end, subtract it.  Total is 0.  Ignore all current directions while doing this.

4) Mark the nodes which have more than 2 currents entering or leaving. Imagine you have N of these. Write Kirchoffs nodal equations for N-1 of these.

5) Apply Ohm's law to all resistors to eliminate voltages in terms of currents in the loop equations. **OR** eliminate all currents in terms of voltages in the nodal equations.

6) If you have inductors or capacitors, you need to apply either the derivative relations (for DC analysis) or impedence relations (for AC analysis).  This can make things interesting.

Solve the resulting system of equations for the unknowns. It should be a system of linearly independent equations unless the original problem was over-specified.

Comment: `3) Write Kirchoff voltage loop equations for every ``simple'' loop, i.e., loops which do not enclose other loops` I like this suggestion. From what I can tell, the "complex" loops are all linear combinations of the "simple" loops, so sticking with just the "simple" loops we can avoid a degenerate system of equations. The remaining equations can be created using nodes instead of loops.

Comment: This algorithm only works for planar circuits, i.e., circuits that are topologically equivalent to a planar graph.

Comment: @BenCrowell See the first 3 words of the answer.

Answer (score -2):

I have always found it extremely cumbersome to solve circuits by writing and solving a horrible system of equations. It will always work, but it is not very elegant. For instance, in doing so, you can end up proving the voltage divider formula that you could have used directly. My best piece of advice is to never introduce currents unless explicitly requested. In most exercises you will do during your studies, I guess you will be able to do it way more simply using [voltage dividers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) or [Millman's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millman%27s_theorem), the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle), and in the most extreme cases [Kennelly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform). If none of it works, then you can write your whole system of equations.